# Fonts turning bold, not supposed to

Tags: css

Okay, I'm not going to post the entire css code for your own sake lol, but it's here http://pattersoncode.ca/incls/style.css

Anyway, I don't know whether it's a problem with my browser (Safari 7) but whenever the page fully loads, all the writing turns bold, and it looks out of place.

As you can see, I've set font-weight: normal !IMPORTANT on many areas of my code to see if that would solve it, but it didn't.

Comment: use a DOM inspector to check one of the bolded elements. any inspector worth its salt will tell you what CSS rules have been applied, and where they come from. Use that to backtrack where the bold is coming from.

Comment: +1 use an inspector. The webkit inspector is my personal favorite (comes with Chrome/Safari).

Comment: can you post a fiddle with the html?

Comment: "whenever the page fully loads, all the writing turns bold" => sounds suspiciously close to some script deciding to set an inline style (or perhaps something not as heavy-handed?) on these elements. I 'd try turning off the scripts before going to the CSS.

Comment: Did you try using a [CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/)?

Comment: also you have a typo in your CSS, its `font-size` not `fontsize`

Comment: Use jsbin.com or jsfiddle.com as alternative to code pasting or linking

Comment: see http://jsbin.com/iwixoc/1/edit there is nothing bold. Try clearing your browser cache (shift +  f5)

Comment: I guarantee you have a label or H2 that isn't closed properly.

Comment: I second that. You could at least post your html.

Comment: You do seem to have some markup issues.  One of which is divs outside of your body block: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpattersoncode.ca

Answer (score 0):

I guarantee you have a `LABEL` or `H2` that isn't closed properly. You have only have only 2 elements with a bold definition: `LABEL` and `H2` If you have closing tags missing or out of sequence, the style will cascade in the document, making everything bold.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Google's @font-face declaration is overwriting your own font-weight. That may be because Google's Font CSS comes right AFTER your style.css. Try placing Google's font-face css BEFORE your style.css, like this:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://pattersoncode.ca/incls/style.css">
```

Then reset overwrite font-weight again in your style.css